# Cant get text drom input tag by DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new in JavaScript and I am wondering to get some text from two fields.
after a user click on confirm. texts print in Result section.
It does not work as I expected. After you confirm, you should refresh the page once, for second time it works!

```js
var personalInfo = {
  firsName: document.getElementById("name").value,
  familyName: document.getElementById("family").value,
  confirm: function confirm() {
    document.getElementById("show-name").innerHTML = personalInfo.firsName;
    document.getElementById("show-family").innerHTML = personalInfo.familyName;
  }
}
```

```html
<div> Basic Information</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
    <td>Family Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="family"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="personalInfo.confirm()">Confirm</button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<hr>
<div> Result!</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name & Family name:</td>
    <td><span id="show-name"></span> <span id="show-family"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, `personalInfo.firstName` and `personalInfo.familyName` are set to the values of the DOM elements **when you're declaring** `personalInfo` variable. You should replace them with functions getting the values of the DOM elements **when the button is pressed** (when `personalInfo.confirm()` runs):

```js
var personalInfo = {
  firstName: function () {return document.getElementById("name").value},
  familyName: function () {return document.getElementById("family").value},
  confirm: function() {
    document.getElementById("show-name").innerHTML = personalInfo.firstName();
    document.getElementById("show-family").innerHTML = personalInfo.familyName();
  }
}
```

```html
<div> Basic Information</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
    <td>Family Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="family"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="personalInfo.confirm()">Confirm</button>
<br>
<hr>
<h3> Result:</h3>
<div>Name: <span id="show-name"></span></div>
<div>Family name: <span id="show-family"></span></div>
```